# Changing Motor Mounts

Tags: engine, ford, focus

My 2007 Ford Focus ZX3 SES (65k miles ) has a vibration at all engine speeds.  Other research has led to a high probability that this is from worn out motor mounts.

I have read after market replacements will typically wear out again in a few months and that I should get them from Ford.  True?

I have also read that all three should be changed at the same time, or the others will go bad very quickly after one is changed.  True?

I've watched some videos about changing them, and it looks to be pretty straight forward.  However, they all use an impact wrench in the videos.  Do I need one, or could this be done with regular hand tools?  Do I need a torque wrench also?

Comment: It would be interesting to know how you have arrived at the conclusion that your vibration is from the engine mountings. Are they visibly split or oil soaked? Have you considered that you may have a clutch starting to fail (manual trans) or torque converter (auto). Misfiring engines would also be a cause of a vibration. The crankshaft pulley on a lot of engines carry a vibration damper. If this damper has gone bad this would also cause a vibration that you describe. Please comment.

Comment: I searched around and the motor mounts seems to be a common cause.  I've poked around on focus fanatics for instance.  It is a manual trans, but the other causes you mention are certainly possible.  The mounts struck me as something I could myself and would at least rule out as a cause if I changed them.

Answer (score 1):

1. The longevity of the aftermarket mounts will depend on their quality. You will get what you pay for. My suggestion is get the OEM ones from Ford unless you want to get polyurethane inserts (depends if you are enhancing performance for track use or not - I am assuming not)
2. If you don't mind doing the job again in a while then just change the damaged one and wait and see if the others deteriorate. If they are close to needing replacement then now is a good time to change them, but otherwise leave them. I changed a single mount in my Honda and haven't had an issue with the others, granted it hasn't been long.
3. I don't think you will need an impact wrench. A torque wrench will be needed to get them torqued to the manufacturers specifications.

Comment: You're correct, I'm not enhancing performance, I just want to get rid of this vibration issue.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check if your front hydraulic engine mount is broken/worn is to jack up the front of the car....place another small jack with a piece of wood as a cushion under the oil pan/engine and jack the engine up slightly to remove pressure from the engine mount....run the engine....if the vibration is gone/less replace the motor mount....most cases it will be the passenger side motor mount but do a check on the internet to see which mounts wear out 1st....I recently changed the passenger side motor mount with an after market part on my 2007 Ford Focus SE, 4 door sedan (80,000 mi.)....takes about 30 min. and it cleared up my vibration problem....good luck...

Comment: Yes, from my research, it is most likely the passenger side, but I can do the test you described and see if that is the case.  Thanks for that!